# text left, image right

Tags: floats

I have have an issue with wrapping and alignment of the an image within a paragraph.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\textwidth 165mm \textheight 230mm \topmargin -5mm
\oddsidemargin 0mm

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\columnsep}{1cm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\allowdisplaybreaks
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=black, citecolor=blue, urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

    \bibliographystyle{plainnat}
    \setcitestyle{semicolon,round,aysep={,}}
 The following sections.\\ \noindent\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}
\section*{Introduction} \label{sec: intro}
This is the intro
\section{Problem} \label{sec: prob}
This is the problem description. This is the problem description.This is the problem description.This is the problem description.This is the problem description.This is the problem description.This is the problem description.This is the problem description.This is the problem description.This is the problem description.This is the problem description.This is the problem description.This is the problem description.This is the problem description.This is the problem description.This is the problem description.This is the problem description.This is the problem description.This is the problem description.This is the problem description.This is the problem description.This is the problem description.This is the problem description.This is the problem description.This is the problem description.This is the problem description.This is the problem description.This is the problem description.This is the problem description.This is the problem description.This is the problem description.This is the problem description.
\vfill
\begin{minipage}{0.35\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{download}
\end{minipage}\hfil
\begin{minipage}{0.55\linewidth}
\end{minipage}
This is the problem description. This is the problem description.This is the problem description.This is the problem description.This is the problem description.This is the problem description.This is the problem description.This is the problem description.This is the problem description.This is the problem description.This is the problem description.This is the problem description.This is the problem description.This is the problem description.This is the problem description.This is the problem description.This is the problem description.This is the problem description.This is the problem description.This is the problem description.This is the problem description.This is the problem

\end{document}
```

Comment: What are you trying to obtain, exactly?

Comment: Try moving your `\end{minipage}` (`minipage` is currently empty) to be _after_ the content.

Comment: @Bernard, hey Bernard, I want the text on the left and the image on the right sides of the page. and not exceeding the margins. Wrapping issues

Comment: You didn't even use the `wrapfigure` environment! What did you load the package for?

Comment: Have you tried setting the text width, margins, and margin paragraph spacings with the geometry package and then using a `\marginpar` command to put the figure on the right?

Comment: @siracusa: DONE

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that `\end{minipage}` was *before* the content. So instead of

```
\begin{minipage}{0.35\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{download}
\end{minipage}\hfil
\begin{minipage}{0.55\linewidth}
\end{minipage}% <------------------- Too early
 ... content ...
```

You should have had

```
\begin{minipage}{0.35\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{download}
\end{minipage}\hfil
\begin{minipage}{0.55\linewidth}
 ... content ...
\end{minipage}% <------------------- Moved from above
```

### Notes:

- The `demo` option was used on the `graphicx` package as I don't access to the figure "download". This option should be removed in your actual use case.
- Consider using the `geometry` package to set the page dimensions.
- Also, please try to eliminate code that is not needed to reproduce the problem.

### Code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}% <--- "demo" option as I don't have access to "download" image.

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{0.35\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{download}
\end{minipage}\hfil
\begin{minipage}{0.55\linewidth}
%\end{minipage}% <------------------- Moved this line to end
This is the problem description. This is the problem description.This is the problem description.This is the problem description.This is the problem description.This is the problem description.This is the problem description.This is the problem description.This is the problem description.This is the problem description.This is the problem description.This is the problem description.This is the problem description.This is the problem description.This is the problem description.This is the problem description.This is the problem description.This is the problem description.This is the problem description.This is the problem description.This is the problem description.This is the problem
\end{minipage}% <------------------- Moved from above
\end{document}
```